# How to change the color of system notification drawer?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, colors, background-color

I am developing default phone app. It provides in call UI.

**My efforts :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#e91e63"
tools:context=".CallActivity">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/NumberField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="@string/CallerPhoneString"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/CallTime"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/NumberField"
    android:text="@string/CallingTypeString"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_functions"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/hold_join_speaker"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/hold_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/hold_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/not_on_hold"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hold_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/hold_text_string"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/join_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/reject_text_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/join_calls"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/reject_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/join_text_string"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/speaker_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/speaker_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/speaker_off"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/speaker_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/speaker_text_string"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mute_sms_record"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mute_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mute_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mic_on"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mute_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/mute_text_string"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sms_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/sms_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/in_call_sms"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sms_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/sms_text_string"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/record_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/record_button"
                style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:background="@drawable/in_call_record"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/record_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/record_text_string"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ActionLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" >

        <com.ncorti.slidetoact.SlideToActView
            android:id="@+id/slideToAnswer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            app:area_margin="8dp"
            app:text="Slide to answer"
            app:text_color="@color/colorWhite"
            app:text_size="20sp"
            app:text_style="bold"
            app:slider_height="90dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_End_Call"
            style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:background="@drawable/disconnect"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />



    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**How it looks when running on device :**

[image: like this]

**What is the problem ?**

The system area ( i think notification drawer ) where network tower, battery percentage is shown is completely unreadable due to the white like color, How can i keep it default or change it to some proper color which will enable users to read things in system drawer easily.

Thanks in advance, And any help is appreciated.

**Edit 2 : ( on Demand )**

Theme used is - `AppTheme.NoActionBar`

This is the theme mentioned in manifest :

```
<activity
        android:name=".CallActivity"
        android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_call"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter android:priority="800">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_CALL" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**and my Theme Styles.xml :**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" 
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" 
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

Thank you.

**Edit 3 : ( Tried the suggestion ) :**

I edited the styles as :

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorBlue</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" 
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" 
parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

1. Added the attribute `android:statusBarColor` to green
2. Saved and run it over device, which not worked.
3. Invalidated caches and restarted Android Studio
4. Updated the App version from build.gradle so that device will look for new changes instead of using caches in previous version
5. Still not changed the color of status bar to blue

**Edit : 4 ( What else i tried )**

It changed the color programatically via

```
this.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorBlue));
```

Still i am looking for changing it Styles wise.

**Edit 5: ( On Success )**

v21/Styles.xml was having the default color which creating the issue. As suggested and answered by @Md. Asaduzzaman Changing this perticular Styles file resolved the problem by :

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/black</item>
```

> Now this thread is beautiful and has 3 answers
>
> 1. By programatically via activity
> 2. By changing Styles for above v21 and for v21
> 3. By using `BarUtils` too

Comment: Can you add your `Theme` that you applied on that `activity`?

Comment: In case of api level 21 and up you can use `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>`

Comment: What is your device API level?

Comment: No, API level of the device where you test the app.

Comment: Do you have variants of theme like `styles.xml(v21)`, `styles.xml(v23)`?

Comment: Check  **v21**, Probably you have used `transparent` color there

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman, You helped me to find the Problem also directed keenly, Now we have 2 answers to the question, If possible you can write a answer so that in future community will get benefitted. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `android:statusBarColor` in your `Theme` **v21**

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/holo_red_light</item>
```

Probably you have used `android:color/transparent` in one of your theme variants like:

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

If so, **Remove** that from your theme.

Comment: It is targeted API 29

Comment: It really helped apreciated upvoted and accepted as answer process made 3 available answers for future visitors. Great

Answer (score 1):

How about use the [BarUtils](https://github.com/Shouheng88/Android-utils/blob/master/utils/src/main/java/me/shouheng/utils/ui/BarUtils.java) of my open source android utils library [Android-utils](https://github.com/Shouheng88/Android-utils).

You need only:

1. call `BarUtils#setStatusBarColor()` to set the status bar color;
2. then call `BarUtils.addMarginTopEqualStatusBarHeight(/*root view of your layout*/)` or use `fitsystemwindow` property in your layout.

This will first use transparent status bar, and then add a fake view with given color you set as the status bar.

For sample, you can reference to the [MainActivity](https://github.com/Shouheng88/Android-MVVMs/blob/master/sample/app/src/main/java/me/shouheng/sample/view/MainActivity.kt) of my another project [MVVMs](https://github.com/Shouheng88/Android-MVVMs).

Hope it helps.

Comment: But my solution desn't have the API limit if only it's above KITKAT. @RushikantPawar

Comment: Yes indeed. Your answer is helpful too. But it always better to treat the root cause and the cause was the Styles (v21) file. Your answer will be helpful in future too. Thank you and Upvote for your sincere help

Answer (score 0):

Use android:statusBarColor in your Theme v21 it will require Api level 21.

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorBlue</item>
```

You can change color from Api 19 onwards using style in values-v19.
[image]

Style in values-v19:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    //transparent status bar
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>


</style>
```

This will make the Status Bar transparent and you can set Background to change the status bar Color.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

                     window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.statusBarColor));

    }
```